# how to identify the function a website uses to decode data received from an "application / octet-stream" API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, web-scraping, decode

I am trying to scrape the site "https://aiscore.com" where I already identify that it makes its requests via API, example: https://api.aiscore.com/v1/m/api/match/total?match_id=vrqwni3v1o1u4qn&lang=5

in which the data is somewhat eligible as in the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6x2.png

My question is how can I transform this data that I receive "application / octet-stream" into the json format? I know that somewhere in the js code processed by the browser there is a function that handles this data and transforms / decodes it, but I'm having trouble solving this.

Comment: Are you sure that it is json? It looks binary-ish to me.

Comment: I simply need to transform from the format that I receive "application / octet-stream" to something eligible, in which json is possible, in the same way that some function already in the source code does in which I couldn't find out which one.